# FFMPEG - Converting MKV to MP4 on Gdrive using rclone mount. ERROR: output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert video files from my back-up rip files library that I have on my Gdrive account. I was successfully able to set up a dedicated server + plexserver + rclone + gdrive. I have files that are big and my family are not able to stream them due to the poor internet service that I have in my country. So I am trying to reduce the file size so it can be streamed directly

My rclone mount script is:

```
rclone mount gcache: /path  --tpslimit 5 --allow-other --acd-templink-threshold 0 --stats 1s --buffer-size 64M --timeout 5s --contimeout 5s --max-read-ahead 1G --drive-chunk-size 64M -vv &
```

And my ffmpeg script is:

```
ffmpeg -i origen.mkv -c:v copy -movflags faststart -strict -2 convertedfile.mp4
```

I had the following errors:

```
moov atom not found
```

I used this command:

```
AtomicParsley myVideo.mp4 -P
```

Now when I execute

```
ffmpeg -i convertfile.mp4
```

I get this error:

```
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

What am I doing wrong? I need some help please.